# Operations with surds (Pre-calculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried multiple ways to solve this:

$$ \left (2\sqrt 8 - 3\sqrt 5 \right)^2 $$

([original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRaEi.png))

and my answer was way off. Can someone show me their method? Thanks.

Comment: As a professional mathematician, I have never heard of a "surd" before.  Is this an invention of the k-12 teachers?

Comment: @StevenGubkin It is a very ancient term, which has somewhat fallen into disuse in the last seventy or eighty years.  It is certainly not an invention of the k-12 teachers.

Comment: Nearly identical: [Simplify the surd expression.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658736/simplify-the-surd-expression) (My simplifying comment applies here as well, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to prevent any careless mistakes is to apply the identity

$$(a - b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab$$

Substitute $a = 2\sqrt{8}$ and $b = 3\sqrt{5}$. Then we have 
$$a^2 = (2\sqrt8)^2 = 4\cdot8 = 32$$
and
$$b^2 = (3\sqrt{5})^2 = 9\cdot5 = 45$$
and
$$2ab = 2\cdot2\sqrt8\cdot3\sqrt5=12\sqrt{40}$$

So we have
$$(2\sqrt{8} - 3\sqrt{5})^2 = 32 + 45 - 12\sqrt{40} = 77 - 12\sqrt{40}$$

Comment: You forgot to add the two -6's at the end, other than that marked as answered. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Oops, my mistake! fixed.

Comment: Do not forget to simplify $12\sqrt{40}$ to $24\sqrt{10}$ :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember the formula:
$$(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$$
Apply it to your expression $(2\sqrt{8}-3\sqrt{5})^2$. But first, simplify $2\sqrt{8}$ to $4\sqrt{2}$. Now we have to find the value of:
$$(4\sqrt{2}-3\sqrt{5})^2$$
Use the $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ formula.
$$a=4\sqrt{2}$$
$$b=3\sqrt{5}$$
$$(4\sqrt{2}-3\sqrt{5})^2=(4\sqrt{2})^2-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})+(3\sqrt{5})^2$$
Remember, $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$.
$$(4\sqrt{2})^2-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})+(3\sqrt{5})^2=4^2(\sqrt{2})^2-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})+3^2(\sqrt{5})^2$$
$$4^2(\sqrt{2})^2-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})+3^2(\sqrt{5})^2=16(2)-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})+9(5)$$
$$16(2)-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})+9(5)=32-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})+45$$
$$32-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})+45=77-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})$$
Now we will simplify $2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})$.
$$77-2(4\sqrt{2})(3\sqrt{5})=77-2(4)(3)(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{5})$$
Rememeber. $\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$.
$$77-2(4)(3)(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{5})=77-24\sqrt{2\cdot 5}$$
$$77-24\sqrt{2\cdot 5}=77-24\sqrt{10}$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\therefore \left(2\sqrt{8}-3\sqrt{5}\right)^2=77-24\sqrt{10}}$$